# Linq-to-xml where or clause

Tags: linq-to-xml, where-clause

I'm trying to query two attributes in an xml file for a search term.

I have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Products>
  <item ProductName="Golf Shirt" Content="This is a nice breathable shirt for golf." />
  <item ProductName="Bowling Ball" Content="This is a colorful 8-lbs ball." />
  <item ProdcutName="Tee Shirt" Content="100% cotton tee-shirt." />
</Products>
```

I want to query both the ProductName and Content attribute values on the search term.

Here's my query expression:

```
var results = from node in _xDoc.Descendants("Item")
    where node.Attribute("Content").Value.Contains(searchTerm)
    where node.Attribute("ProductName").Value.Contains(searchTerm)
    select new SearchModel()
    {
    Name = node.Attribute("ProductName").Value,
    Url = "the url",
    Group = "Products"
    };
```

If my search term is "shirt", I should return "Golf Shirt" and "Tee Shirt", but I get nothing.  I think it's because the double "where" clause is creating and "and" expression, and I need an "or" expression. If I remove one of the "where" clauses, it works.

I tried putting a "||" after the first "where" clause, but that generates an error.

How to I implement an "or where" clause for Linq-to-Xml?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
where ((string)node.Attribute("Content")).Contains(searchTerm) || ((string)node.Attribute("ProductName")).Contains(searchTerm)
```

?

Comment: yes I just figured it out and it's very similar to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Here's my fix.

```
var results = _xDoc.Descendants("Item")
    .Where(c => 
        (
            c.Attribute("ProductName").Value.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm.ToLower()) ||
            c.Attribute("Content").Value.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm.ToLower())
        )
     )
    .Select(c => new SearchModel()
         {
             Name = c.Attribute("ProductName").Value,
             Url = "the url",
             Group = "Products"
         });
```